Excel Vba how to reference a caption from another sub
I'm running into an issue where I need to use the caption function to jump between active workbooks and transfer data etc. The problem is when I try to use the established caption in another sub within the same module it references it as being empty?
not sure where I'm going wrong.
Sub Main Code
Sheets("Weekend").Activate
RCDwindow = ActiveWindow.Caption
etc etc etc
call run weekend

Sub runWeekend()
  Windows(RCDwindow).Activate   'here is where the caption is now showing as empty
etc etc

I've walked through my code but cant see the issue. I'm sure the solution revolves around the runweekend sub recognising the established caption

Have a read of How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA.  You shouldn't have to use Activate at all.  There's not enough code to suggest a work around though.

Variables are local to the functions and subroutines in which they are declared. You have created RCDWindow inside of Main Code subroutine and so it only exists in that subroutine. Instead you'll want to pass your variable to the runWeekend subroutine. Check out arglist and the examples at the subroutine documentation page

@JNevill Well, you can create Module-Level or "global" variables, which might be what's going on here, considering that OP hasn't explicitly declared the RCDwindow in their code.  But, that's being very generous, and I doubt it.  They (Microsoft) should really make the Option Explicit option Enabled by Default, instead of needing to be typed or turned on in the Options…

@Chronocidal I avoided mentioning globals since it makes for ugly code. It's definitely a quick-fix option through to toss a declaration outside a sub/function scope for this variable and let 'er rip.

Please share the complete code and a short description of what the code should do so we can apply reasonable improvements as suggested by Darren Bartrup-Cook and JNevill.

You have to declare the variable RCDwindow at the top of the module and then run your Main Code as seen below. This will let you use the value of the variable in every procedure in the module.
Dim RCDwindow As String

Sub Main Code
Sheets("Weekend").Activate
RCDwindow = ActiveWindow.Caption
etc etc etc
call run weekend

Sub runWeekend()
  Windows(RCDwindow).Activate   'here is where the caption is now showing as empty
etc etc


Have you tried passing the RCDwindow variable 'ByRef' to your function?
You mention this is in the same sub, right?
It's been a while since I've been in vba, but I would imagine something like this:
Sub Main Code
Sheets("Weekend").Activate
RCDwindow = ActiveWindow.Caption
etc etc etc
call run weekend(RCDwindow)

Sub runWeekend(ByRef window)
  window.Activate   
etc etc

